# How can I disable the logging of MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, centos

My MongoDB Log file is over 16GB, the log file is not important to me. How can I disable the logging of MongoDB and if I do, will I encounter any problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would not be a smart idea to turn off logging. Use [Rotate Log Files](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/rotate-log-files/) to rotate them and keep them small.

[logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) is standard function on Linux.

Simplest way to rotate the log file is `kill -USR1 $(/usr/sbin/pidof mongod)`

My `logrotate.conf` file looks like this:

```
missingok
compress
delaycompress
notifempty
create

/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log{
  size 10M
  rotate 9
  sharedscripts
  postrotate
    kill -USR1 $(/usr/sbin/pidof mongod)
  endscript
}
```

When the logfile reaches 10MB then it is rotated. Up to 9 files are kept. logrotate is executed by a daily cron job.

Though you can [disable logging](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-systemLog.quiet), it is really not recommended.