# MongoDB fails to rotate logs, keeping deleted files open

Tags: mongodb, logging

I have a similar problem to what was reported in [1], in that the MongoDB log files are being kept open as `deleted` when a log rotation happens. However, I believe the underlying causes are quite different, so I created a new question. The long and short of it is that when this happens, which is not all the time, I end up with no Mongo logs at all; and sometimes the deleted log file is kept for so long it becomes an issue as its size becomes too big.

Unlike [1], I have setup log rotation directly in Mongo [2]. It is done as follows:

```
systemLog:
  verbosity: 0
  destination: file
  path: "/SOME_PATH/mongo.log"
  logAppend: true
  timeStampFormat: iso8601-utc
  logRotate: reopen
```

In terms of the setup: I am running MongoDB 4.2.9 (WireTiger) on RHEL 7.4. The database sits on an XFS filesystem. The mount options we have for XFS are as follows:

```
rw,nodev,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota
```

Any pointers as to what could be causing this behaviour would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time.

**Update 1**

Thanks to everyone for all the pointers. I now understand better the configuration, but I still think there is something amiss. To recap, In addition to the settings telling MongoDB to reopen the file on log rotate, I am also using the `logrotate` command. The configuration is fairly similar to what is suggested in [3]:

```
# rotate log every day
daily

# or if size limit exceeded
size 100M

# number of rotations to keep
rotate 5

# don't error if log is missing
missingok

# don't rotate if empty
notifempty

# compress rotated log file
compress

# permissions of rotated logs
create 644 SOMEUSER SOMEGROUP

# run post-rotate once per rotation, not once per file (see 'man logrotate')
sharedscripts

# 1. Signal to MongoDB to start a new log file.
# 2. Delete the empty 0-byte files left from compression.
postrotate
    /bin/kill -SIGUSR1 $(cat /SOMEDIR/PIDFILE.pid 2> /dev/null) > /dev/null 2>&1
    find /SOMEDIR/ -size 0c -delete
  endscript
```

The main difference really is the slightly more complex `postrotate` command, though it does seem semantically to do the same as in [3], e.g.:

```
kill -USR1 $(/usr/sbin/pidof mongod)
```

At any rate, what seems to be happening with the present log rotate configuration is that, *very infrequently*, MongoDB appears to get the `SIGUSR1` but does not create a new log file. I stress the "seems/appears" as I do not have any hard evidence of this since its a very tricky problem to replicate under a controlled environment. But we can compare the two scenarios. I see that the log rolling is working in the majority of cases:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 SOMEUSER SOMEGROUP 34M  May 5  10:51 mongo.log
-rw-------. 1 SOMEUSER SOMEGROUP 9.2M Feb 25 2020  mongo.log-20200225.gz
-rw-------. 1 SOMEUSER SOMEGROUP 8.3M Nov 17 03:39 mongo.log-20201117.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 SOMEUSER SOMEGROUP 8.6M Jan 30 03:19 mongo.log-20210130.gz
-rw-------. 1 SOMEUSER SOMEGROUP 8.6M Feb 27 03:31 mongo.log-20210227.gz
...
```

However, on occasion it seems that instead of creating a new log file, MongoDB keeps hold of the deleted file handle (note the missing `mongo.log`):

```
$ ls -lh
total 74M
-rw-r--r--. 1 SOMEUSER SOMEGROUP 18M Feb 17 03:29 mongo.log-20210217.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 SOMEUSER SOMEGROUP 18M Feb 18 03:11 mongo.log-20210218.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 SOMEUSER SOMEGROUP 18M Feb 19 03:41 mongo.log-20210219.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 SOMEUSER SOMEGROUP 15M Feb 20 03:07 mongo.log-20210220.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 SOMEUSER SOMEGROUP 6.5M Mar 13 03:41 mongo.log-20210313.gz

$ lsof -p SOMEPID | grep deleted | numfmt --field=7 --to=iec 
mongod  SOMEPID SOMEUSER 679w      REG              253,5       106M 1191182408 /SOMEDIR/mongo.log (deleted)
```

Its not entirely clear to me how would one get more information on what MongoDB is doing upon receiving the `SIGUSR1` signal. I also noticed that I get a lot of successful rotations before hitting the issue - may just be a coincidence, but I wonder if its the final rotation that is causing the problem (e.g. `rotate 5`). I'll keep on investigating but any additional pointers are most welcome. Thanks in advance.

[1] [SO: MongoDB keeps deleted log files open after rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60734785/mongodb-keeps-deleted-log-files-open-after-rotation)

[2] [MongoDB docs: Rotate Log Files](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/rotate-log-files/)

[3] [How can I disable the logging of MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66887553/how-can-i-disable-the-logging-of-mongodb/66888748#66888748)

Comment: How to you rotate your log?

Comment: Rotation is to distribute  logs based on date, everything else, deletion etc. needs to take place on OS level.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66887553/how-can-i-disable-the-logging-of-mongodb/66888748#66888748 Be aware, in a proper logrotate you **first** move/delete the logfile, then the `logRotate` command is executed.

Comment: Hi, I believe the ```logRotate: reopen``` is triggering the rotation. Or do you think otherwise? I got the impression from this comment on the manual: "You can also configure MongoDB to support the Linux/Unix logrotate utility by setting systemLog.logRotate". [2, in main comment]

Comment: So @WernfriedDomscheit, if I understood you correctly, you think then that using log rotate externally is a better option instead of using MongoDB's internal log rotation? We can certainly try that, but I was hoping that the MongoDB solution would be the more reliable option.

Comment: When reporting activity data to a log file, by default, MongoDB only rotates logs in response to the logRotate command, or when the mongod or mongos process receives a SIGUSR1 signal from the operating system.

Comment: Aha, so I need to figure out what is actually doing the log rotation on my config. OK, it all makes sense. Let me have a look for that then. Thanks very much everyone.

Comment: If you use `logRotate: reopen`, then logging is typically done in conjunction with `logrotate` or similar - as stated in [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#systemlog-options). Of course you can use MongoDB internal log rotation (i.e. `logRotate: rename`), however then you still need to invoke your OS to delete the old logfiles.

Comment: Actually, I wonder if our "cleverness" on post-rotate is not causing this issue, e.g. ```find /SOMEDIR/ -size 0c -delete```. Maybe some kind of race condition. I will remove this and see if it makes any difference.